# VISUAL BASIC .NET

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

how to update null visual basic.net 2012 ,,,

```
 sql="Update mytb set name='' where no_ktp='"& sed.text &"' "
```

that's cannot 
HElp me please . its form my job school

Comment: What are you talking about?  In what way is this code not doing what you expect it to do?  You have to describe the problem, nobody here can see your screen or knows what you're working on.

Comment: im sorry ,,, that code cannot work

Comment: i have just used it , i have not understood

Comment: Then perhaps you need to start with an introductory tutorial on Visual Basic .NET?  Nobody here can help you unless you can describe an actual problem that you're experiencing.  If the problem is that you don't understand what code is or how it works, then the solution would be to start with some tutorials and learn the basics.

Comment: i have done ..
i canot update give null for my value table

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to update a tables where a certain value was present, you should use something like the following :

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE mytb SET name = NULL WHERE no_ktp = @sed"
```

**Use Parameterization, Not Concatenation When Building Queries**

You should **not** be building your database queries like this. It is going to leave you prone to issues with incorrect syntax and possible SQL Injection attacks.

Instead consider adopting an approach like the following that takes advantage of SQL Parameterization and should help avoid issues similar to those previously mentioned :

```
' Build a Connection to use '
Using connection = New SqlConnection("{your-connection-string}")
    ' Open your connection ' 
    connection.Open()

    ' Build your query (using parameters) '
    Dim query = "UPDATE mytb SET name = NULL WHERE no_ktp = @sed"

    ' Build a command to execute '
    Using command = New SqlCommand(query, connection)
        ' Add your parameters '
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sed", sed.Text)
        ' Execute your update '
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tb_kamar SET no_ktp=NULL WHERE no_kamar='" & Val(cbnokam.Text) & "' ", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

Comment: data mismatch expression

Comment: Rion Williams Help me

Comment: You are still using string concatenation, which is a no-no. Additionally if you are using `OleDbCommands`, they don't support named parameters, so [you'll want to use something like this revised code instead](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/f984cbaef10e846e5c841aef5c8fbec0).

Comment: I do not understand . Please help me .
please use simple language .i not proficient in English

Comment: You are currently using string concatenation to build your query (i.e. "SET NAME = '" YourTextBox.Text + '"). This allows the user to type whatever they want in your TextBox and have a chance at that code being executed, which is dangerous. The code that I provided in the previous example should work for your needs.